# Read csv file and play cue when encountering row > y

Tags: python, pandas, pygame

So far I have tried this code, however, it gives me two errors: 1- `pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123.dll` and 2- my data is considered as DataFrame, not integers.
so, I was wondering how can I fix these two errors. 
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pygame
doc=pd.read_csv('Data.csv', usecols =[3])
doc= doc [1:10]
df= doc.astype(int)
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("song.mp3")
for i in df:
    if i > 9:
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```py
df = doc.values
```

instead of

```py
df= doc.astype(int)
```

for your second error. The .values attribute converts your dataframe values to numpy array.